# Overriding Celltable Column getCellStyleNames method returns null

Tags: gwt, celltable

I tried to override the getCellStyleNames(Context context, T object) method of Column. But its not working.

I tried to return super.getCellStyleNames(), but it returns null.

What is the problem? What am I supposed to do to fix this problem?

I am using GWT 2.6.rc1.

```
TextColumn<ContactInfo> firstNameColumn = new TextColumn<ContactInfo>(
            ) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(ContactInfo object) {
            return object.getFirstName() ;
        }

        @Override
        public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, ContactInfo object) {
            Window.alert("X ::: "
                    + super.getCellStyleNames(context, object));
            return "cellTableCell1";
            // object.getAge() % 2 == 0 ? "cellTableCell2"
            // : "cellTableCell1";
            // return "styleName";
        }
    };
```

Thanks In Advance,
Bennet.

Comment: have you tried with GWT 2.5.1 ?

Comment: Tried, but same problem again. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying simply to override the default celltable style or something else?

Comment: Create a style in custom.css and add that in the View with the interface declared and method for the style. Create instance for the style and using that style to return from the overridden method.

Comment: your method returns "cellTableCell1" so why you think is not working?

Comment: But, the style is not applied to the cell. Its taking only the .cellTableEvenRow and  .cellTableOddRow, but not the one which I supplied.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42403/discussion-between-bennet-and-fedy2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion in chat we discovered the issue: the style name "cellTableCell1" was declared inside the table CSS resource, therefore the name was obfuscated. Getting the name from the CSS resource solved the issue.